# How to Disable QLPreviewController print Button

Tags: ios, pdf, qlpreviewcontroller

Can anyone tell me how to remove the QLPreviewController print button?  Also would like to disable cut/paste/copy.

Comment: For a solution for iOS6, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083546/qlpreviewcontroller-hide-print-button-in-ios6

Comment: work fine for me using Xcode 8.3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45344701/1603380

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:**

This no longer works in iOS 6. Quick Look runs in another process using XPC. See [here][3] for more details. I don't foresee any way to customize QLPreviewController. The following answer remains for anyone interested for pre-iOS 6.

---

If you want to simply remove the action button you need to subclass `QLPreviewController`. Then in `-viewWillAppear:` you need to remove the action button by calling `[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:nil];` This will also remove the ability to share files with other apps. If you are fine with that loss, then that's the easiest solution. One thing to be aware of is that `QLPreviewController` is NOT intended to be customized. You can check out this [repository](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBFilePreviewer) on Github. It contains a QLPreviewController that is already safely subclassed. You just need to add the one line to remove the action button. The repo also has some other conveniences.

The better but more complicated solution is to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. From what I understand of `QLPreviewController` is that it's built using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. `QLPreviewController` was made for general use and easy addition. `UIDocumentInteractionController` gives much more control, but is harder to use. I can't sufficiently describe how to use it here. I recommend checking out WWDC 2010 session 106 Understanding Document Interaction Controller.

As for disabling cut/copy/paste, you can't do that with `QLPreviewController`. You might be able to do that with `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but I wouldn't count on it. Depending on what files you want to display, you may be able to do a completely custom implementation, but that's a lot of work. It's relatively easy to make viewers for plain text, photos, videos, and PDFs. Office documents are more effort than it's worth.

**EDIT:**

I've built the ability to remove the action button right into `RBFilePreviewer` so you don't have to worry about doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Only worked when I setRightBarButtonItem:nil in "viewDidAppear"

Comment: -viewDidAppear is an odd place to put that. Does it work in -viewWillAppear? That would be much better if possible. Also, are you going to upvote/accept my answer as correct?

Comment: It turns out that removing the action button isn't as trivial as I thought. QLPreviewController has a lot of quirks underneath. RBFilePreviewer now has that feature built in and takes care of all the different cases. Plus, I fixed a "bug" in the original QLPreviewController that causes it to not show the document navigation bar when pushed instead of being presented modally. You can also see a demo of RBFilePreviewer in my demo repository: https://github.com/rob-brown/Demos.

Comment: @rbrown: I have started to test QuickLook framework and I'm experiencing weird leak when testing on iPhone 3GS + iOS4.0. The leak appears even when using pure framework. However, no leak appears when using iPhon 4 + iOS 5.0. Recently, I have posted the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992308/strange-leak-when-using-quicklook-framework-in-ios4-0  It would be interesting if you could test that leak too :)

Comment: RBFilePreviewer no longer works as of iOS6 :( At least, not for the removing buttons part...

Comment: It does not work for iOS 8 GM Seed. Some other suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

If you subclass `QLPreviewController` and then add this one method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:nil]; 
}
```

in the subclass, the action button will disappear as rbrown notes above. This will not work if you use `viewWillAppear`. Also, an unexpected side-effect of doing this is that the toolbar on the preview now appears at all times, instead of just when you tap the view.

Comment: This does not work, as well as previous answer by Neogene Sparanza, in case you have many documents to preview - everything becomes like before this after you change the document.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItems = nil;
}
```

Works for me instead of `[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:nil];`

Comment: Works for me too but the arrows next and prev button have curiously disappear leaving two black empty button.

Answer (score 1):

I also need to custom the navigaiton item of `QLPreviewController`. Just like [rbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371357/rbrown) said, XPC is used and we can no longer add custom items in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Currently I use this way:

1. create a new class of `UIViewController`
2. add the view of `QLPreviewController` to the new class

It seems wired but works.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in this way:

```
UIView *viewPreviewController; //from storyboard

QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
[previewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.viewPreviewController.frame.size.width, self.viewPreviewController.frame.size.height)];
[previewController.navigationController setHidesBarsOnTap:YES];
previewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil;

[self.viewPreviewController addSubview:previewController.view];
```

If i had not incorporate the previewController in a UIView, then it would not work!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to disable the`rightBarButtonItem` in `QLPreviewController` that works fine for me in iOS8 and iOS9

You simply need to subclass `QLPreviewController` and override the following methods, then use your subclass instead of the original `QLPreviewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // When coming back from background we make sure the share button on the rightbBarButtonItem is disabled
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        weakSelf.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; // Disable the share button
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; // Disable the share button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me . you have to debugg child navigation controller

```
class QLSPreviewController : QLPreviewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true )
        //This hides the share item
        if let add =  self.childViewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
            if let layoutContainerView  = add.view.subviews[1] as? UINavigationBar {
                 layoutContainerView.subviews[2].subviews[1].isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This subclass works with **Swift 4.2** and **iOS 12**. It uses a trick to make sure that the share icon is hidden without flashing in the eyes of the user.

```
import QuickLook
import UIKit

class PreviewController: QLPreviewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        guard let layoutContainerView = self.children.first?.view.subviews[1] as? UINavigationBar else { return }
        layoutContainerView.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        guard let layoutContainerView = self.children.first?.view.subviews[1] as? UINavigationBar else { return }
        layoutContainerView.subviews[2].subviews[1].isHidden = true
        layoutContainerView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue with:

```
let previewVC = QLPreviewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    previewVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
}
```