# How to add UIBarButtonItem to QLPreviewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, qlpreviewcontroller

I already read this question [QLPreviewController remove or add UIBarButtonItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957091/qlpreviewcontroller-remove-or-add-uibarbuttonitems) but it's not what I'm looking for. I would like to **keep the "Print" button** in the navigation Bar but **also add** a new "Delete Document" button in the navigation bar.

I tried this:

```
QLPreviewController *previewer = [[[QLPreviewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[previewer setDataSource:self];

UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Salva Documento" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(saveFileToDocuments)];
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[previewer navigationItem]rightBarButtonItem],saveButton, nil];
[[previewer navigationItem]setRightBarButtonItems:buttons];
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: are you building to support iOS 5 and newer ***only*** or iOS 4.X and/or iOS 3.X?

Comment: it's an app for iPad only, so 5 and 4.x will be fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said "4.x will be fine", there's your problem.

The documentation for `UINavigationItem` [`[setRightBarButtonItems: animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setRightBarButtonItems%3aanimated%3a) (documentatin linked there for you) say that this function only works on iOS 5.0 and newer.

It will **not** work on iOS 4.0.

Also, you should add an `animated:` parameter to that `setRightBarButtonItems:` call.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through each line of code and see if a `nil` object is being referenced.  For example, I see multiple references to `[previewer navigationItem]`.  Assign that to a variable via `UINavigationItem * previewerNavigationItem = [previewer navigationItem];` and then see if it's nil.  Also, check if `[previewer navigationItem]rightBarButtonItem]` is returning nil also.

Comment: previewerNavigationItem is not nil, but almost everything inside it, is  0x0 (like title, left and rightBarButtonItem)... Is it possible that those object are loaded when the controller is pushed into the stack? If so, how should I add that button to the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes... you are on the right track. Push the controller onto the stack *first* and then do your customizations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIBarButtonItem *rbb;
-(void)addRightButton{
    if (!rbb) {
        UIButton *orderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        orderButton.frame = CGRectZero;
        rbb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:orderButton];
    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rbb;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(addRightButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self addRightButton];

}
```