# How to open and view .xlsx files in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I can download documents which can be of types `.pdf`,.`xlsx`,`.jpeg`,`.tiff` etc from an API. If I use `UIWebView` it doesnot support `.xlsx` and `.msg` files.

How can I view these files.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Download documents in iOS ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `QLPreviewController` to display all of these types of files.

A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

- iWork documents
- Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
- Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
- PDF files
- Images
- Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
- Comma-separated value (csv) files

Comment: I have an option to take screenshot.So if I am using QLPreviewController, I only can view files , on taking screenshot ,that screen will be fully blank since ios 6 the QLPreviewController is actually a completely seperate app (seperate process and everything)so when you push that, your whole app moves to the bg, including its window and gesture recognizers So I can't use QLPreviewController

Comment: `QLPreviewController` is just a `UIViewController` that you present like any other view controller in your app.

Comment: When I take the screenshot after subviewing the qlpreviewviewcontroller, that is blank. Can you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675378/ios-6-uigestures-tap-stops-working-with-qlpreviewcontroller and let me know whether my assumption is right or wrong?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if that is correct or not. I use `QLPreviewController` in my app and it does what I need. For me, the implementation details don't matter.

Comment: @AswathyBose Aswathy, I have the same EXACT issue you have.  I need to take a screenshot upon opening it, so I have to use UIWebView.  But it doesn't support XSLX.  Did you ever find a solution to this?  Thanks.

Comment: QLPreviewController, incredibly, has no callbacks to tell you when the document has loaded. So this is not a solution. Any others please?

Answer (score 0):

use this code u will get satisfied

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:file type];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

try this it will help you to make zimmicks with any type of file