# E-mail account information with QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using `QLPreviewController` for showing the pdf. And I am sending pdf by tapping the share button and then tap on email in the `QLPreviewController`.

But i don't know how to get that share button method in `QLPreviewController` to validate that the email account is available or not. Here is the screenshot:

[image]
Please let me know about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to check if a email account is valid or not?

Comment: @Rashad....Yes i just want to check that email account is setup in the device or not....

Comment: What do you mean by setup in the device? That email is store in the device or the device is using the email?

Comment: I mean that when i tap on send email button and if there is no email account setup(Store)in the device there should be an alert message...

Comment: See the `MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail:` method.

Comment: But where i put this method because i am using QLPreviewController..

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about any of this. If the user's device is not setup with email, the activity view shouldn't show the Mail option.

Comment: But its showing the email option if the device is not setup with email....is there any way to show an alert..?

Comment: @rmaddy ... yes its not showing the email...but i want to add an alert there...is it possible..?

Answer (score 0):

if you have `UInavigationController` then you can add a bar button for sharing the content. Or you can add a share button in your viewcontroler.

Use `MessageUI`. Add the delegates `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.

```
- (IBAction)contactBtn:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [controller setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [controller setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:NO];
        [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a@wa.com",nil]];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed!" message:@"Mail can not be sent. Check your email settings." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: @Rashad.....i am using QLPreviewController and when QLPreviewController open there is some options for sharing pdf or file...and when i tap on mail button it will open the Mail composer...but i am not able to detect the button actions of sharing..So i am not able to add the above method...SO please let me know where i put this method in QLPreviewController

Comment: Where is your sharing button? in navigation bar?

Comment: It is in the QLPreviewController and i am not able to detect this sharing button method....

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Can you tell me how to share screenshot here...?

Comment: Select edit in your question. Then you can find a button squre in green color.

Answer (score 0):

The QL previewer is working on separate process. Something like a different app. So there is no way to customize the share button. see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675378/ios-6-uigestures-tap-stops-working-with-qlpreviewcontroller/13332457#13332457)

This may help you. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957091/qlpreviewcontroller-remove-or-add-uibarbuttonitems).