# Laying white toolbar over QLPreviewController toolbar is looking gray

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar, qlpreviewcontroller

I stumbled upon [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957091/qlpreviewcontroller-remove-or-add-uibarbuttonitems) on adding/removing qlpreviewcontroller's uibarbuttonitems. However they were removing the navigation bar and overlaying a new one on top of it.

I was looking to change the toolbar primarily because the toolbar that comes with QLPreviewController is black and the rest of the toolbars in my application are white.

I have code in place to get the bar overlaying but it seems that when I set the toolbar tint color to white, its actually becoming a light gray. I was thinking that this was because the toolbar was not opaque but after setting alpha to 1.0 it still looks the same.

**Relevant toolbar code from class extending QLPreviewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    ....

    self.overlayToolBar?.setItems([actionBtn], animated: false)
    self.overlayToolBar?.tintColor = .blue
    self.overlayToolBar?.barTintColor = .white
}
```

**Toolbar from previous screen**

[image]

**Toolbar from QLPreviewController screen**

[image]

**Original Toolbar for QLPreviewController**

[image]

Is there a different/better way to set the toolbar color? Since QuickLook runs through XPC I can't edit the toolbar directly. Thus I have to do this roundabout *hack* to get a customized toolbar on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when I was attempting to not show all of the items on a QLPreviewController.

I ended up subclassing the QLPreviewController:

```
import QuickLook

class PreviewController: QLPreviewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow I totally over thought this whole thing... I googled myself down a hole I guess! Goof on my end.