# Disable action items in UIDocumentInteractionController's presentPreviewAnimated

Tags: ios, ipad, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController's presentPreviewAnimated method to preview document.  It works fine.  But I wish to disable the action button while in the preview mode. I have the following two delegated methods to return NO.  But these two methods never got called at all.  The other delegated methods work fine.  Any suggestion?

```
-(BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller canPerformAction:(SEL)action {
NSLog(@"canPerformAction");
return NO;
}
```

and

```
-(BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller performAction:(SEL)action {
NSLog(@"performAction");
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally switched to use the QLPreviewController class.  Where you can subclass it and make the action button gone away.  (With the help from the answer by rbrown of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918210/how-to-disable-qlpreviewcontroller-print-button).